# Passenger use wrong Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I installed Ruby 2.1.2 via `rvm install 2.1.2`, but Passenger uses 1.9.3 where my gems aren't available.

After I found the error, I tried to change the `passenger_ruby` to `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2` but I got this error:

```
App 30033 stderr: *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2: Permission denied (13)
```

so I switched back to the normal Ruby version using:

```
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

And with `/usr/bin/ruby` I get this error document: 
http://jsfiddle.net/p3pde70d/

So how can I change the Ruby version to 2.1.x for Passenger?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't use a link to jsfiddle to show the error you got. Instead, copy the stack trace and paste it into your question, correctly formatted to make it readable. Links are subject to rot and will break and be useless, making your question of no use to anyone else.

Comment: @theTinMan, I tried to paste the stacktrace here but I didn't get it right formatted. Maybe you can paste the Stacktrace from jsfiddle?

Comment: It's not hard to do, you just need to read the help document for formatting text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely need to install bundler under the system ruby.

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Though for running ruby 2.1.x, I recommend not using rvm or rbenv with a server setup. It's better to install a new version of ruby for that system. I typically will just compile the version I want from source. No idea what OS you're on, but for a debian system, can do something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

That grabs all necessary software to compile things like ruby.

```
cd ~
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.2.tar.gz # you may need to install wget through apt-get

tar xvf ruby-2.2.2.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.2.2.tar.gz
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Watch for errors on the configure step. It will tell you if you are missing any further dependencies. After it completes successfully, system ruby should be updated. From there install bundler :)

Comment: I usw debian 7 :)
how I can uninstall rvm? Should I reinstall the whole server? Or only uninstall rvm?

Comment: Don't need to start over or anything. You may need to re-install passenger, but i'm not certain. For rvm `rvm implode` should do the trick. Can also just delete the .folder under `~`. Be sure to update any bashrc files that added rvm to path.